# Run DataBricks notebook in repo parent directory (/Repos?)

Tags: python, databricks

In DataBricks, I am attempting to use `%run` to run a notebook in the current notebook's parent directory:

```
%run "../notebook_name.py"
```

The problem I'm running into is that the path it's finding for the notebook starts with `/Repos` when it should start with `/Workspace/Repos/`, so it's obviously not finding the notebook in question.

The following code has the exact same problem:

```
notebook_path = dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().notebookPath().get()
```

I could use that code anyway to build the correct path and use `dbutils.notebook.run`, but I want to bring the variables, functions, and modules defined in the notebook into the current notebook's scope, which `dbutils` does not do.

Please note that I am looking to use a relative path, as in the example above, not a full path.

What options do I have to address this?

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

It should work just fine - most probable error is that you're specifying the file extension for your notebook, although you don't need it.  See [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/en/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html) for more information.  This [example](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-nutter-repos-demo/blob/master/unit-tests/test_with_percent_run.py#L6) works just fine for many years :-)

```
%run ../Code1
```

Another reason could be that your file isn't a notebook (it should have `# Databricks notebook source` as a first line), but a Python file - in this case you can use Python imports instead (see [this example](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-nutter-repos-demo/blob/master/unit-tests/test_with_arbitrary_files.py#L11)).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you want is to import the module, specially because your file has a `py` extension.

You can do `import <path_within_your_repo>.notebook_name.py` . You can see the import paths available in your python notebook with:

```
import sys

print(*sys.path, sep="\n")
```

Anything relative to one of those paths will be found by `import`.

You may find useful to reload the module each time, to make sure you pick up any changes to it whenever you rerun the cell (import only loads modules the first time they are requested).

```
import mymodule
import importlib
importlib.reload(my_module)
```